# Comparing OLS and ML through log likelihood value

Tags: maximum-likelihood, least-squares, likelihood

The log-like likelihood values that are computed when I do a regression (by for instance eviews), are they comparable for different estimation techniques, specifically OLS and Maximum Likelihood? My intuition is that they are comparable when ML is done with a normal distribution, because I think that then the likelihood function should be the same as that of OLS (because OLS assumes normality of the disturbances). However, when ML is not done with a normal distribution, I think that they cannot be compared. Is this correct? Or can they be for instance compared asymptotically in some cases maybe?

Comment: In general, the OLS estimation method does _not_ assume normality of the disturbances. Indeed it is a widely used formulation (OLS + Normality), but it is not a defining characteristic of the method.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Yes you are right. But let's say that in this question OLS means OLS with normal disturbances.

Comment: If you *define* OLS to be with the assumption of normality and still insist on comparing with something that asserts non-normality, in what way could you compare them. I find your comment confusing.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify the remainder of the post: there's little point in trying to beat maximum likelihood away from the normal. One of the main reasons MLE is widely used is that under very mild conditions it will always do at least as well as the most efficient estimator possible in large samples. This is because one of its major properties its [asymptotically efficiency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood_estimation#Properties). Least squares is not asymptotically efficient in general. It is BLUE, but that's little use when every linear estimator is bad.

Nevertheless, given its simplicity, it may make some sense to at least consider *how close* least squares may do compared to MLE. As estimators (outside of any given sample) given you must have some model to compare them at, you can calculate the asymptotic relative efficiency of least squares to ML, or (equivalently) to the Cramer-Rao lower bound. In cases where it's possible to compute the small sample efficiency, you can compare those as well, or simulation can be used to compare efficiencies. For the remainder of the answer I will focus on comparisons within a given sample.

There are a variety of ways one might compare OLS and MLE fits.

One can clearly compute the likelihood or log-likelihood for a fit not obtained by ML (obviously ML does better -- because it maximizes the likelihood).

One can as readily compute the sums of squares of residuals for OLS and ML (obviously OLS wins -- because it minimizes this criterion).

One can compute some other measure of fit than either the likelihood or SSE.

An obvious class of distributions to consider would be the exponential family, and the use of GLMs. It includes the normal as a special case.

We can do regression for a gamma model and using OLS quite readily:

[image]

We might evaluate the likelihood for the OLS fit by substituting its parameter estimates into the likelihood function for the mean parameter in the gamma (if we use shape-mean parameterization).

Comment: Does your post actually answer the OP question, ie "whether likelihoods from different estimation techniques, such as OLS vs ML assuming non-normality, are comparable"? Thanks!

Comment: To me that question is resolved by "obviously ML does better -- because it maximizes the likelihood" ...

Comment: not really, because the OLS coincides with the ML assuming normal errors, as OP notes. This leaves open OP's question of whether one can compare a LL from OLS/ML-normal to some LL assuming `ML is not done with a normal distribution` (in which case each will maximize their own likelihood)? Thanks!

Comment: I have added some material at the top of the post.